# Break Loop After First Iteration

Tags: java

I have a List that contains many rows of data.What i want to do is return only the first iterated value and nothing else.

```
public int getnumber() {    
    for (Bike temp : bikes) {
        return temp.getBikeID();
        break;
    }
}
```

I tried something like the above..but the break statement is unreachable. How may i achieve this ?

I know that i could still just declare a variable outside of the loop then assign the value in the loop but the returned value will be the last row.

Comment: Why don't you simply do (after checking the size of the list and if the first element is not null)`public int getnumber(){return bikes.get(0).getBikeId();}`?

Comment: Thanks it's just my inexperience :p

Comment: you are doing a return before you break... then the execution is finished there.

Comment: What's being returned if there is no bike in `bikes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the `return` statement before `break`. The `return` statement will take the execution to the calling method. so, the break statement is unreachable.

You don't need to iterate to get the first value of the collection. The first index  would be `0`. so, just make it

```
if(bikes!=null && bikes.size() > 0)
return bikes.get(0).getBikeId();
return -1; // `-1` denotes failure or put anything relevant to failure
```

Comment: @aliteralmind I have updated the code to handle failure situation. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Do not loop and try directly :

```
 return bikes.get(0).getBikeId();
```

Comment: Will fail if there is no first element, unlike the loop approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this  -

```
// null and size check to make sure if there is something on 0 index
return bikes != null && bikes.size > 0 ? bikes.get(0).getBikeId() : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete the `break` statement. In fact, this is all you need:

```
for (Bike temp : bikes) return temp.getBikeID();
return -1;
```

In place of `return -1` put the behavior you prefer for the "not found" case.

Answer (score 1):

You can access you list's indices via `.get()` directly. No need for an iteration if you only need **one** or a **hand full** of specific elements:

```
public int getnumber() {
    int result = 0;

    if (bikes != null && bikes.size() > 0)
        result = bikes.get(0).getBikeID();

    return result;
}
```

Or even shorter, with the use of the **ternary operator** (`condition ? true : false;`):

```
public int getnumber() {
    return (bikes != null && bikes.size() > 0) ? bikes.get(0).getBikeId() : 0;
}
```